# Break a number down to banknotes

Tags: java

Was given the below excercise in college but can't get my head around the last bit. How do you brake the answer down to notes. what if the answer can't be devided by 50 etc...
I've tried modulus & Math class....

> Mr Cashman, the owner of the local corner shop is having trouble with
>   his staff giving the wrong change.  To tackle this he has commisioned
>   you to create a program that allows the staff member to enter the
>   total cost of the shopping and the amount the customer has paid. The
>   program should then calculate and output how many €50, €20, €10, €5
>   notes, and how many €2, and €1 coins to give the customer as change. 
>   Mr. Cashman refuses to deal with small coins so although the staff
>   member enters a decimal value for the cost of the shopping he rounds
>   all of his prices down to the nearest euro and doesn't bother with
>   50c, 20c, 10c, 5c, 2c or 1c coins.
>
> Write, compile and test the application as per Mr Cashmans
>   requirements and save the class as MakingChange.java

Comment: modulus and math is definitely the way to go

Comment: Mr Cashman seems to be a bad businessman.

Comment: I'm only in my 4th week, take it easy. It's the maths part that has me confused. It's not homework, but an extra excercise that I'd like to understand. @VincenzoSanchez some horrible attitude..

Comment: @user1743358 Being new in college doesn't really entitle you to special treatment. Your question is "bad" on its own merit - the expectation on SO is that you'll have done as much research and work on your own as possible, and then ask about a specific problem you're having. "How do you break a number down into banknotes" is just rephrasing the entire assignment, a specific question would have been something like "how do I find out how many 50s fit into a given sum?" If you were actually asking about the latter, you phrased it rather badly, it follows that some people might not understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right approach with modulo, but integer division is needed as well. Let's examine the value €164.

If you divide 164 by 50 (with integer division), you get 3. So that's 3 €50 notes needed.

If you work out 164 *modulo* 50, you end up with 14, the value left after you've taken out those three €50 notes. That's you starting point for the next iteration with €20 notes.

Then you just keep doing it until you've exhausted all the currency types.

In other words, the pseudo-code could look something like:

```
def workOutNotes (numEuros):
    left = numEuros
    //                               for 164:      numXXs   left
    num50s = int (left / 50); left = left % 50; //      3     14
    num20s = int (left / 20); left = left % 20; //      0     14
    num10s = int (left / 10); left = left % 10; //      1      4
    num5s  = int (left /  5); left = left %  5; //      0      4
    num2s  = int (left /  2); left = left %  2; //      2      0
    num1s  = left;                              //      0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try this! We were told to do it the long and hard way (not learned the 'code' def workOutNotes (numEuros): 'code' yet)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a piece of C# code for you, which basically breaks down the change into smaller and smaller bills:

```
int changeAmount = 1300;
var bills = new int[] { 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 };

var changeBills = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(int bill in bills)
{
    changeBills.Add(bill, changeAmount / bill);
    changeAmount = changeAmount % bill;
}
```

The code cuts the change to fit into the bills, not the amount of shopping. But I think it is fair to let you add this logic.